# cant access web app on browser

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

recently my boss asked me to migrate our web application from xampp on windows to ubuntu server. 
I already install Apache server, MySQL and php based on this website :

[How To Install and Secure phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Apache web server is running and I can access the phpmyadmin menu too.
so I copy all my web folder that located on `xampp/htdocs/myweb` into `var/www/html/myweb`. then I make a database on phpmyadmin then upload my `database.sql` to it. everything seems work to me. but the problem is, when i open myweb using `ubuntuserverip/myweb` it can't. there's this notification. [can't access notfication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEA6q.jpg)

Comment: See if you can connect to the database from Ubuntu terminal, and be sure your app credentials are ok.. use tis `mysql -u root -p` to connect from terminal

Comment: @george i can access the mysql -u root -p but i still can't open it from browser.

Comment: Do mysql root user have the same password as before?

Comment: yup,, exactly same as before @RomeoNinov

Comment: Please post the result of `ls -al  var/www/html/myweb` What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu server 14.04 @George

Comment: @george actually i put all my app folder directly to /html
http://imgur.com/a/B7UrG

Comment: That's wrong they should be in `/var/www/html/myweb` that's how it works in Ubuntu...Each of your apps should have their own folders in `html`...please move them into `myweb` dir in `html`

Comment: And again please don't follow a tutorial for an older version of Ubuntu than yours its bad practice and a recipe for disaster ...

Comment: @George. i'll try then let see what happen. thx